# wchar_t is not treated as built-in type even when the option is enabled

Tags: visual-c++, visual-c++-2008

So here is the **preprocessed** output of a struct:

```
typedef struct RPT_Item
{
    wchar_t *fullPath; 
    RPT_ItemFlags_t itemFlags; 




    int isComposite;
    const void *reserved; 
} RPT_Item_t;
```

Visual Studio complains because `wchar_t` is not defined, its own cryptic way:

```
error C2016: C requires that a struct or union has at least one member
```

I looked at the project files and also at the particular C file where the error appears and I can confirm that "**Treat wchar_t as built-in type is set to YES**".

If I define the type using a typedef it compiles fine.

I used the preprocessor output so I can exclude that some nasty preprocessor `#define` trick play the main role.

This project contains many low-level hacks, for example the CRT is not linked (`/NODEFAULTLIB`).

Most of the code is not written by me, and I'm tasked to remove reference to wchar.h from a public header that uses wchar_t, because VS treats it as a built in type default. (This particular module is built only on Windows.)

I totally ran out of ideas. Is there a compiler option or a pragma that can interfere? Or could it be even a compiler bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft didn't explicitly document this until VS 2013, but [the docs for `/Zc:wchar_t` says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dh8che7s.aspx)

> The `wchar_t` type is not supported when you compile C code.

It seems that including nearly any header from the runtime or from the SDK will typedef `wchar_t` to`unsigned short` using the following sequence:

```
#ifndef _WCHAR_T_DEFINED
typedef unsigned short wchar_t;
#define _WCHAR_T_DEFINED
#endif
```

you might want to do something similar in your file that uses `wchar_t`.

Note that when compiling a C++ file, if `/Zc:wchar_t` is in effect then the compiler pre-defines `_WCHAR_T_DEFINED`. If `/Zc:wchar_t-` is in effect it doesn't - so the above snippet should work nicely with C++ as well (for MSVC anyway - I don't know how other compilers might deal with this if you're looking for something portable).

The `_WCHAR_T_DEFINED` macro is documented:

- [MSVC Predefined Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx)